# After upgrade to OSX Mavericks, fetchmail fails to call procmail

Tags: osx-mavericks, procmail, fetchmail

I just upgraded from OSX Snow Leopard to Mavericks, and now fetchmail fails to invoke procmail.  Mutt is also not working, but that is a different story.

The following poll (with names changed) has worked for several years:

`poll pop.1and1.com
     protocol: pop3
     username: abc@example.org
     password: 123123123
     nokeep
     fetchall
     mda "/opt/local/bin/procmail -d %T" # pass message to the local MDA`

After upgrading to Mavericks, it correctly polls the POP3 server, but fails with the following message:

`fetchmail: about to deliver with: /opt/local/bin/procmail -d 'tbaker'
 #****fetchmail: MDA died of signal 6
 not flushed`

The newly installed /opt/local/bin/procmail is the super-stable v3.22 of 2001/09/10, and 
my default $HOME/.procmailrc and system mailbox have not changed.

I assume I'm not the only one with this problem so am surprised not to find any threads about this.

Tom

Comment: I found a similar post in another forum from someone who solved the problem by getting procmail from the backup of his old system and installing under Mavericks.  I did this and it worked!  Problem solved.

Comment: Please post that as an answer and accept it so that this question no longer shows up as unresolved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: I found a similar post in another forum from someone who solved the problem by getting procmail from the backup of his old system and installing under Mavericks.

I retrieved fetchmail, procmail, and mutt from the Time Machine, installed them. Also installed putmail.py, which had been deleted from /usr/bin. Everything works now! Problem solved.

Lessons learned: The Mavericks upgrade hoses Unix.  Unix tools compiled under Mavericks may not work correctly.  Unix tools from previous versions of OSX may continue to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Talked to Apple a few days ago.  They are aware of the problem and plan on fixing it with their next update.  In the meantime I was told to take the account offline and put it back online when you want to fetch mail.  This is kind of a pain in the butt but it works and hopefully they will get it fixed soon.